# Avoiding long case statement on argument class

Tags: vb.net, polymorphism, case-statement

There is a class hierarchy of tasks that can be performed by the class A.

Inside the class A there is a long case statement checking for the task class  and calling the correspondent handler method.

```
Class Task
End Class

Class TaskX
Inherits Task
End Class

Class TaskY
Inherits Task
End Class

...


Class A
    Public Sub PerformTask(Task As Task)
        Select Case Task.GetType
            Case GetType(TaskX)
                PerformTaskX(CType(Task, TaskX))
            Case GetType(TaskY)
                PerformTaskY(CType(Task, TaskY))
        End Select
    End Sub


    Private Sub PerformTaskX(Task As TaskX)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PerformTaskY(Task As TaskY)
    End Sub

    ...
End Class
```

The tasks have their individual parameters, validation logic, etc. The example is simplified.

I want to avoid the case statement and I am looking for alternative solutions.

The general idea is mapping a class type to a Handler(Of class) that could work somehow like this:

```
Delegate Sub Handler(Task As Task)

Private TypeToHandlerDict As New Dictionary(Of System.Type, Handler) From { _
            {GetType(TaskX), AddressOf PerformTaskX}, _
            {GetType(TaskY), AddressOf PerformTaskY} _
        }
```

so that I can replace the PerformTask method contents with the much more elegant:

```
Public Sub PerformTask(Task As Task)
    Dim handler As Handler = Nothing
    If Not TypeToHandlerDict.TryGetValue(Task.GetType, handler) Then Exit Sub
    handler(Task)
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work.

The delegate binds to type Task, but the handler methods accept a task subclass parameter. I am using Option Strict.
I could rewrite all handler methods to accept a Task object and perform an explicit cast, but this is equally inelegant.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

**Update**: Here is the solution thanks to the answer from @Sehnsucht.

```
Class Task
    Public MustOverride Sub Perform(a As A)
End Class

Class TaskX
Inherits Task
    Public Overrides Sub Perform(a As A)
        a.DoThis()
    End Sub
End Class

Class TaskY
Inherits Task
    Public Overrides Sub Perform(a As A)
        a.DoThat()
    End Sub
End Class

...


Class A
    Public Sub PerformTask(Task As Task)
        Task.Perform(Me)
    End Sub


    Public Sub DoThis()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoThat()
    End Sub

    ...
End Class
```

Comment: Can you add a `Perform` or  `Execute` method to the Task classes and let them do the work?  Maybe using an `ITask` interface if needed.

Comment: Can you put PerformTask as a must overrides function inside of Task and them each TaskX implement their own version? That way you just call task.PerformTask()

Comment: Not for nothing but you have asked 8 questions and gotten 10 answers, but not marked any of them as accepted.  Accepting the best answer, if any, and upvoting helps other users find good answers.  The [tour] explains this and other things in very brief form.

Comment: I commented in the answer of Sehnsucht.

@Plutonix: Thanks a lot for the hint! I'll give a look in all my asked questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `PerformTask...` have the same signature and that's enforced by the delegate `Handler` you showed in your post.
So you should make an Overridable method in your `Task` class with a default implementation (or mark the method as MustOverride if the Task class is MustInherit), method which will be overrided by it's inheritors to do the job according to their specific case.

```
Class Task
    Public Overridable Sub Perform()
        ' implementation specific to Task ("default" case)
    End Sub
End Class

Class TaskX
    Inherits Task

    Public Overrides Sub Perform()
        ' implementation specific to TaskX
        ' you can call the parent implementation if needed with
        MyBase.Perform()
    End Sub
End Class

'Usage
Class A
    Public Sub PerformTask(task As Task)
        task.Perform() ' will call the "right one" according to it's runtime type
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Executing a task involves business logic inside the class A ("_how_ should it be done"), while a task only knows about "_what_ should be done".

Creating an Execute method with a class A parameter in the task and letting the task call exposed business logic of the class A is possible, though I don't like this solution.

Comment: @Manolis it was never stated that Tasks classes only contained data about the *what* and not the *how*. Almost the opposite, for me, when you stated that each task has individual parameter, validation logic... it implied for me that each one knowed *how* it would perform. With that extra info your comment in addition of the initial post I would maybe have answered differently :-)

Comment: Apparently the only solution that works, is indeed to make use of the polymorphism and to make each Task descendant able to perform itself.

In order to implement this in our system, I need to expose some logic of the class A and change the polymorphic Perform method of Task so as to accept A as parameter, so that it can call the logic it wants to.

Thank you!